# Can you set properties to beans when using component-scan?

Tags: spring

Is it possible to set properties to beans when they are auto-detected?

I have a bean which would need to read a text file and I'd like to inject the path, but this bean is part of a web app where all beans are auto-detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes just inject them using `@Value` annoation, eg :

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyService

    @Value("${myProperty}")
    String whatever;
...
```

and then in app context :

```
<context:property-placeholder
  location="classpath:application.properties"
  ignore-unresolvable="true"
/>
```

stick file application.properties containing your string vars in your classpath (normally via src/main/resources).

Or you could just make sure your file is on classpath, and reference that as classpath resource

```
final org.springframework.core.io.Resource myFile = new ClassPathResource("MyTextFile.text");
```